# rsync: No space left on device (28)... with a lot of free space

Tags: linux, rsync, disk-space-utilization

I need to make a copy of 200GB in a 500GB external SSD disk to a 2TB NVMe M2 SSD, which has more than 1TB free. All my other disks and partitions have lots of GBs of free space, too (well, except for the boot partition).

Yet, when doing a `rsync`, I see a **No space left on device (28)** error with around 20 files:

```
rsync: [receiver] rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr("/extraHD/TEMP/<some folder>/RECEBIDOS/423___ KWR Designer ___ Neu++ Tuto \#302\#251 Christa  JA.eml","user.OECustomProperty") failed: No space left on device (28)
```

Some facts:

- The folder `RECEBIDOS` has 444 files and 465MB, so nothing really special.
- Running again `rsync` gives the very same errors on the very same 20
  files.
- Adding `--inplace` to `rsync` does **NOT** solve the issue
  (as expected).
- Trying to make a `rsync`of the `RECEBIDOS` folder
  alone gives the very same errors on the very same files (this points to a problem on the external 500GB SSD), yet `cp`
  individual files do work.
- After the progress finishes, I did both `diff`
  and `sha1sum` at each individual problematic files and all of them
  are identical. So no loss.

Could it be some hardware issue with the receiving 2TB NVMe SSD? A bug in `rsync`?

Strangely, Windows do not even see the 500GB SSD. But this `rsync` error seems to point a problem on the receiving side.

**EDIT**

By request, I'm adding the output of two commands:

```
$ /usr/bin/df -h

Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs             16G   24K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            6.3G  1.9M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/nvme1n1p2    40G   13G   25G  34% /
/dev/nvme1n1p1   511M   58M  454M  12% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1p4   165G   55G  102G  36% /backups
/dev/nvme0n1p1   1.8T  1.2T  554G  69% /extraHD
/dev/nvme1n1p3    30G  6.0G   22G  22% /home
tmpfs             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /tmp
tmpfs            3.2G   72K  3.2G   1% /run/user/500
/dev/mapper/key   35G   13G   20G  40% /mnt/key
```

and

```
$ /usr/bin/df -i

Filesystem         Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs          4061241     747   4060494    1% /dev
tmpfs             4066601       7   4066594    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              819200    1291    817909    1% /run
/dev/nvme1n1p2    2621440  265783   2355657   11% /
/dev/nvme1n1p1          0       0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1p4   11010048  400638  10609410    4% /backups
/dev/nvme0n1p1  122101760 1183050 120918710    1% /extraHD
/dev/nvme1n1p3    1966080   83116   1882964    5% /home
tmpfs             1048576      36   1048540    1% /tmp
tmpfs              813320     110    813210    1% /run/user/500
/dev/mapper/key   2293760  138583   2155177    7% /mnt/key
```

Comment: What are the sending and receiving filesystem? Can you show the output of `df -h` and `df -i` ?

Comment: The receiving FS is ext4. The sending one was probably FAT32 (already formatted, sorry). For the output of the commands, please see the EDIT.

Comment: Please show a **complete** rsync command you used.

Comment: The two commands I used were very different, with identical results: `rsync <device1>/<folder1>/ <device2><folder2>/` and `rsync --exclude="lost+found/" --fsync --log-file=/home/gato/.tmp/rsyncdir.LOG -rliHAX --delete --no-itemize-changes --info progress2 -h <device1>/ <device2><folder2>/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error seem to come from attempting to sync xattrs that are too large for the target filesystem.

I got the error by syncing files from btrfs to ext4, a directory had a rather large value in the `user.wine.sd` xattr.

Your problem seem to be the [`user.OECustomProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/f1adfb03-a5ca-49e5-9f0e-c01b7c56c2e3) extended attribute being too large for the target filesystem.

To avoid this error, you can either

1. Delete the extended attribute from the file (but Outlook Express may re-create it).
2. Remove the `-X` flag from your rsync command (but then you won't get any extended attributes copied over).
3. Copy your files to a filesystem which supports larger values for extended attributes instead of ext4.

---

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593173/btrfs-max-xattr-size
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux